# get $request inside loop. Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have multiple answer fields. First answer set is answer0 array second is answer1 array and so on. So I want to take like $request->answer0 , $request->answer1 this.
I need this to be inside a for loop. I tried something like this but failed to get the answer.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arry); $i++) {
    $qstn = new SurveyQuestions();
    $qstn->question_name = $arry[$i][0];
    $qstn->survey_id = $request->survey_id;
    $qstn->survey_group_id = $groupId;
    $qstn->answer_datatype_id = $arry[$i][1];
    $qstn->question_image_path = $qstnfileNames;
    $qstn->save();

    $qstnId = $qstn->id;

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($request->answer . $j); $j++) {
        $ans = new SurveyQuestionAnswers();
        $ans->survey_question_id = $qstnId;
        $ans->answer = $request->answer1[$j];
        $ans->save();
    }
}
```

but this gives me error

> Count(): Parameter  must be an array or an object that implements countable.

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($request->answer); // gives me "1"
```

if I get like this ( $request->answer0 ), I will be able to save answer arrays of particular question id to database.

dd($request->all())

```
array:9 [▼
   "group_name" => "Group 1"
   "survey_id" => "5"
   "question_name" => array:2 [▼
     0 => "q1"
     1 => "q2"
     ]
  "answer_datatype_id" => array:2 [▶]
  "answer1" => array:2 [▼
     0 => "aa"
     1 => "bb"
     ]
  "answer2" => array:2 [▼
     0 => "cc"
     1 => "dd"
     ]
  "group_image_path" => UploadedFile {#394 ▶}
  "question_image_path" => array:2 [▶]
  ]
```

From the above output, I need id of q1 and its corresponding answer1 array to be saved in database. Then with id of q2 and answer2 array to be inserted in database and so on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you do `echo '<pre>'; print_r($request->answer);` and update your question?

Comment: updated.It give me "1".

Comment: You can access dynamic variable like `$request->answer{$i}` and you variable should be an array only then count will return number of element in the array. `count((array)$your_object)` to return count. just a quick suggestion.

Comment: my answer fields are actually like this. answer0[], answer1[]. So when I tried dd($request->answer{$i}) I get a null

Comment: $i should be in for loop with increment 1, answer{$i} $i=0, answer{$i} $i=1

Comment: inside my controller , I gave like this ,to test the result. $j=1;
        dd($request->answer{$j});
But this gives me null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the questions like this:

```
foreach($request->question_name as $i =>$name)
$qstn = new SurveyQuestions(); 
$qstn->question_name = $name;
$qstn->survey_id = $request->survey_id;
$qstn->survey_group_id = $groupId;
$qstn->answer_datatype_id = $request->answer_datatype_id[$i] 
$qstn->question_image_path =$this->question_image_path[$i];
$qstn->save();

$qstnId = $qstn->id; 

$name = "answer".$i;
foreach($request->{$name} as $value)
    $ans = new SurveyQuestionAnswers();
    $ans->survey_question_id = $qstnId;
    $ans->answer = $value;
    $ans->save();
}
```

Comment: only last answer array value is getting inserted for question ids.

Comment: what solution did you use?

Comment: 1st one. With while.

Comment: @madalimivascu : I mistakenly used $j itself instead of $i here, $ans->answer = $request->{$name}[$i]; When I corrected it , for question no. 7 I have answers a,b and for question no.8 I have options x,y. Now in my database for question 7 a and x are inserted and for question 8 b and y are inserted

Comment: you have answer1 an array for question  $i =1 ?

Comment: or you have question $i =1  with answer  answer1[$i],  answer2[$i], etc?

Comment: I have edited my question by adding dd($request->all());

Comment: For my question $i=0 , I have answer1[] array, for question $i=1 I've answer1 array

Comment: Wow.. you really helped me and saved my day :) it works perfect :) Thank you so much :) Accepted this answe and upvoted :)

Comment: glad to be of service

Comment: Hi madalinivascu. I know its been days after this,but've a small doubt. When I delete any question,my response'll becomes something like this:
array: [ "group_name" => "Group 1" "question_name" => array:2 [▼ 0 =>"q1"
     1 => "q3" ] "answer_datatype_id" => array:2 [▶]
  "answer0" => array:2 [▼0 => "aa"1 => "bb" ]"answer2" => array:2 [▼    0 => "cc"
     1 => "dd"
     ]
  ]
Initially I had q1,q2,q3 questions after delete I have q1 ans q2, but they are in index 0 & 1. Their corresponding answers are answer0 & answer2.But on inseret only answers of q1 will get insert not answer2[].

Answer (score 0):

The request should show like this

`$request->answer[0]` not `$request->answer0`

so in your blade or view you should make it like so

```
<input name="answer[]" />
```

in your controller do this

```
for($j=0;$j<count($request->answer); $j++){
    $ans = new SurveyQuestionAnswers();
    $ans->survey_question_id = $qstnId;
    $ans->answer = $request->answer[$j];
    $ans->save();
    }
  }
```

Comment: If I use this answer, then for 1st question and for second question only the answer array of first question gets inserted.